# How to calculate$\int_0^\pi e^{-i c (\sin(t) + \cos(t))} \sin(t)\, dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I would like to calculate the following integral 
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-i c (\sin(t) + \cos(t))} \sin(t) \,dt $$

Here's what I did: We make the change of variables $s=\cos(t)$, so
$$I=\int_{-1}^{1} e^{-i c (s + \sqrt{1-s^2})} \, ds. $$

Answer (score 2):

This probably has no closed form.  Or if it does, it may involve Bessel functions.  See the similar integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi /2}\!{{\rm e}^{ic\sin \left( t \right) }}\sin \left( t
 \right) \,{\rm d}t={\frac {i\pi \,{{\rm J}_{1}\left(c
\right)}-\pi \,{{\rm \bf H}_{1}\left(c\right)}+2  }{2}}
$$
with Struve H and Bessel J functions.